# Python: How to obtain desired list?

Tags: python-3.x, apache-spark, mapreduce

I'm trying to learn Spark so I'm totally new to it.

I have a file with thousands of lines where each one is structured like:

```
LFPG;EDDW;00;E170;370;LFPG;EDDW;189930555;150907;1826;!!!!;AFR1724;AFR;0;AFR1724-LFPG-EDDW-20150907180000;N;0;;;245382;;;150907;1800;0;;X;;;;;;;;;;370;;0;20150907175700;AA45458743;;;;;NEXE;NEXE;;;;;20150907180000;;;;245382;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;AFR;;;;;;;;;;;0
```

The above line represents flight information from an airplane, it took off from LFPG (1st element) and landed in EDDW (2nd element), the rest of the information is not relevant for the purpose.

I'd like to print or save in a file the top ten busiest airports based on the total number of aircraft movements, that is, airplanes that took off or landed in an airport.

So in a sense, the desired output would be:

```
AIRPORT_NAME    #TOTAL_MOVEMENTS    #TAKE-OFFs    #LANDINGS
```

I have already implement this program in python and would like to transform it using the MAP/Reduce paradigm using Spark.

```
# Libraries
import sys
from collections import Counter
import collections
from itertools import chain
from collections import defaultdict

# START

# Defining default program argument
if len(sys.argv)==1:
    fileName = "airports.exp2"
else:
    fileName = sys.argv[1]

takeOffAirport = []
landingAirport = []

# Reading file
lines = 0 # Counter for file lines
try:
    with open(fileName) as file:
        for line in file:
            words = line.split(';')
            # Relevant data, item1 and item2 from each file line
            origin = words[0]
            destination = words[1]
            # Populating lists
            landingAirport.append(destination)
            takeOffAirport.append(origin)

except IOError:
    print ("\n\033[0;31mIoError: could not open the file:\033[00m %s" %fileName)

airports_dict = defaultdict(list)

# Merge lists into a dictionary key:value
for key, value in chain(Counter(takeOffAirport).items(), 
                    Counter(landingAirport).items()):
    # 'AIRPOT_NAME':[num_takeOffs, num_landings]
    airports_dict[key].append(value) 
# Sum key values and add it as another value
for key, value in airports_dict.items():
   #'AIRPOT_NAME':[num_totalMovements, num_takeOffs, num_landings]
   airports_dict[key] = [sum(value),value]  

# Sort dictionary by the top 10  total movements
airports_dict = sorted(airports_dict.items(), 
                        key=lambda kv:kv[1], reverse=True)[:10]
airports_dict = collections.OrderedDict(airports_dict)

# Print results 
print("\nAIRPORT"+ "\t\t#TOTAL_MOVEMENTS"+ "\t#TAKEOFFS"+ "\t#LANDINGS")
for k in airports_dict:
    print(k,"\t\t", airports_dict[k][0],
          "\t\t\t", airports_dict[k][1][1],
          "\t\t", airports_dict[k][1][0])
```

A test file can be download from: https://srv-file7.gofile.io/download/YCnWxr/traffic1day.exp2

So far I've been able to get the very first and second elements from the file, but I don't know quite well how to implement the filter or reduce in order to obtain the frequency time that each airports appears on each list and then merge both list adding the airport name, the sum of takeOffs and landings and the number of takeoffs and landings.

```
from pyspark import SparkContext, SparkConf


if __name__ == "__main__":
    conf = SparkConf().setAppName("airports").setMaster("local[*]")
    sc = SparkContext(conf = conf)

    airports = sc.textFile("traffic1hour.exp2", minPartitions=4)
    airports = airports.map(lambda line : line.split('\n'))

    takeOff_airports = airports.map(lambda sub: (sub[0].split(';')[0]))
    landing_airports = airports.map(lambda sub: (sub[0].split(';')[1]))

    takeOff_airports.saveAsTextFile("takeOff_airports.txt")
    landing_airports.saveAsTextFile("landing_airport.txt")
```

Any hint or guide it will be much appreciated.

Comment: u need to use substr function to extract your columns after reading file, in dataframe API. why use rdd  https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.Column.substr

Comment: File does not have headers, can you still do it without it?

Comment: yes you can specify headers in schema using structtype.